# Dependency injection with constructor parameter in .net core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

I see a lot of code examples on how to use DI in .NET Core, however none of them use constructor parameters.

For example:

- Create Authorization Service
- Inject the current HTTP header(X-Api-Key) in constructor
- In the implementation check if I have access

Here I need to not only use DI on my `IAuthorizationService` but also inject the token in the constructor. I know how to do it in Ninject, however have no experience in .NET Core DI.

Here is what I have as an example.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite();
    services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationService, AuthorizationService>(); // Inject current HttpContext header value as a constructor?
}
```

Comment: [have you seen this documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html)

Comment: Do you need to inject the token, or can you inject the interface for a class that provides the token?

Comment: @ScottHannen Hm, doesn't really matter I guess. However token would be better because testability would be easier then.

Comment: My generic solution: https://gist.github.com/ReallyLiri/c669c60db2109554d5ce47e03613a7a9

Answer (score 8):

I usually flow such values through a service where the data is set in a piece of middleware. For example:

An accessor class which can be injected:

```
public class ApiKeyAccessor
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

And a middleware which sets the API key at the beginning of the request:

```
public class ApiKeyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ApiKeyAccessor apiKeyAccessor)
    {
        StringValues key;
        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Api-Key", out key))
        {
            apiKeyAccessor.ApiKey = key;
            return _next(context);
        }

        // todo: throw exception, etc..
    }
}
```

Now all we have to is add the `ApiKeyAccessor` to the DI container with a **scoped** lifetime and add the `ApiKeyMiddleware` to the request execution pipeline, preferably as soon as possible.

When configured correctly, we can inject the `ApiKeyAccessor` instance in controllers or services:

```
public class AuthorizationService
{
   private readonly string _apiKey;

   public AuthorizationService(ApiKeyAccessor apiKeyAccessor)
   {
      _apiKey = apiKeyAccessor.ApiKey;
   }
}
```

Comment: I like this - injecting a class - more than injecting a value unless the value is something unchanging like a connection string. With any given DI container it's usually easier to inject a class than to configure the container to retrieve a value at runtime.